# Tensorflow Docker Build from source options

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build tensorflow code from source. My goal is to understand the code base and see if there are any areas I can contribute to. To this end
I have cloned the tensorflow source tree from  tensorflow docker shell. When I ran ./configure I got a bazel version error that I fixed by upgrading to latest bazel. Now among the remaining options what would be a minimal set that would result in a successful build without any additional installs? Currently am running into a ComputeCPP not found error. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.
TIA,
EmmaP

Comment: Can you clarify the question? `Now among the remaining options what would be a minimal set that would result in a successful build without any additional installs?` what are the remaining options? Can you link to source?

Comment: From what I can tell from the instructions is that building TF from source is a 2 step process. First run configure and then bazel build. What I am trying to figure out for non GPU build what all options I can leave as N?  I chose 'Y' for ComputeCPP and now it is looking for ComputeCPP lib.

Comment: I was able to get past the issue by selecting N for sysCL and CUDA.

Comment: Great! Glad I could "help" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps I followed to build docker from source on my windows laptop

- Created a Ubuntu 18.04 VM for virtualbox.
- Installed docker.  Went with this option as Docker on windows essentially does the same thing.
- Followed instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) under Docker Linux builds.
- Ran config and went with default options.
- Ran build to create pip package.